# RaspberryPi touch sensor using transistor

Tags: transistors, raspberry-pi, gpio, input, touch

I built the following circuit. When I touch the rogue transistor base wire and GPIO is outputting, the LED lights up (still not quite sure why, so if someone could explain this, that'd be helpful, too.)

[image: My current setup]

But now instead of the LED showing the state, I want to use a GPIO input to send it to the Pi. However when I replace base with GPIO.IN, the LED loses a lot of voltage, and thr GPIO only reads 0 (off). If you couldn't tell, I'm new to all this, so a bit more detail could prove helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your body is an antenna and when you touch the base of this transistor some amount of electricity is coupled into that input of the transistor.  This transistor is setup as an "emitter follower" which means that it will attempt to keep the voltage at the emitter (Ve) at the same level as the voltage at the base (Vb).

So clearly you are raising Vb to a potential that is high enough to turn the LED ON.

Try a circuit like this to read the GPIO input when your transistor base is touched:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQEQia.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea here is that when an input is present on the base of the transistor, it will turn the transistor ON.  When that happens current flows in the collector which will pull the GPIO pin LOW.  Keep in mind that the collector current, Ic, is the base current Ib times the hfe value of the transistor.  For most small-signal transistors hfe is in the 100s or even 1000s.  So you get a sizeable collector current with very little base current.

Comment: That is already very helpful to understand, thanks! Concerning the rest of the question, do you know why the GPIO pin doesn't read the voltage. I could imagine the resistance increasing as the GPIO becomes the ground, but admittingly I don't know at all

Comment: GPIO read what voltage?  It's not at all clear what else you are asking or what you are trying to do.

Comment: Currently the diode leads to a ground connection, from which I cannot read whether the base is touched ( / the LED is on). So I connected another GPIO Pin after the LED, instead of the Ground. However, the LED is dimmed and the GPIO in pin shows a LOW value..

Comment: that's because your circuit is not able to pull the GPIO pin (which I assume is setup for input) to a low enough voltage (i.e. Vil) that is will read a logic 0.

Comment: Okay, if I didn't misunderstand that, your saying the voltage arriving at the GPIO.IN pin is too low, no? So could I switch the 330 Ohm resistor for say 100 without hurting the LED since our resistance overall has increased?

Comment: I just saw the edit you made and will try that as soon as I can. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the answer with a suggested circuit that might help.

Comment: hey jwh20, I finally got to try out your suggestion. It works a lot better than before, so thanks already. However even with this setup, I get inconsistent ouputs, probably due to the touch connection. That is to say that the GPIO.IN jumps at times. It would be lovely if you could point me into the direction, on how I can get a reliable signal, that is to say reliable off state when touch contact is present. Cheers!

Comment: I'm sure the issue is due to random elements in the input signal.  This is similar to switch "bounce" when you might be using a switch on the input of a microcontroller.  The simplest solution would be to handle it in your software by averaging the input over time.  You can also do this in your circuit by introducing a filtering element such as an RC circuit.  I've updated the circuit in the answer to show you a possible solution.  Experiment with different R and C values to see what gives you the desired performance.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the response. However I'm not sure if that is quite the problem. Even when constant touch input without movement is applied, the output still swings. Couldn't it be due to the (rookie speaking) resistance that it is barley enough to register the input, so sight fluctuations are enough to shoot off the correct value? From how I read it, this would more solve the problem if it were only at input change that such fluctuations would arise, but I'm happy to learn if I should be wrong